# URL search parameters gets replaced - Remix Run

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

I'm working on a search UI where I have quite a few filters which I want as URL parameters when someone selects/checks the options. I've used the  technique as advised on the Remix.run docs to come up with multiple forms within the filters. Each time a group of Filters gets submitted, the selected old parameters get disappeared. Heres my code,

```
<Panel header="Status" key="status">
      <Form
        name="search"
        action='/search'
        method="get"
        onChange={(e) => submit(e.currentTarget, { replace: false })}
      >
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Checkbox
              name="status"
              value="buy_now"
              defaultChecked={status.includes('buy_now')}
            >
              Buy Now
            </Checkbox>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Checkbox
              name="status"
              value="on_auction"
              defaultChecked={status.includes('on_auction')}
            >
              On Auction
            </Checkbox>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </Form>
    </Panel>
    <Panel header="Price" key="price">
      <Form name="search" action='/search' method="get">
        <Select
          name="blockchain"
          value={
            blockchain
              ? options.filter((a) => a.value === blockchain)
              : undefined
          }
          options={options}
          placeholder="Blockchain"
          type="white"
        />
        <div className="d-flex align-center price">
          <TextInput
            value={min ? min : undefined}
            name="min"
            placeholder="Min"
          />
          <span>to</span>
          <TextInput
            value={max ? max : undefined}
            name="max"
            placeholder="Max"
          />
        </div>
        <button
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.stopPropagation()
            submit(e.currentTarget, { replace: false })
          }}
          className="btn primary-btn btn-lg w-100"
        >
          Apply
        </button>
      </Form>
    </Panel>
```

How Can I get around this to have all the parameters without having to manage them on my own using React state?

Edit:- I want the first filter to be submitted automatically and the latter to be submitted on a button click.

Bit of a UI of what I'm trying to achieve,

[image]

Answer: After investing enough time to look through for shortcuts, finally understood that it's not one of the magic that remix.run does. use something like formik and update the state imparatively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you submit a form, the only values included are the one under the submitted form. The values from any other form are not included (fortunately!).

So I'd use a single Form with all the inputs under it (checkboxes as well as text inputs).
Then instead of a `onChange` on the Form, you can add something like an `onChange` handler on the checkboxes and submit the form inside imperatively (using a ref click on the submit button or something, I think using a ref on the form you need to submit all values in the submit function so a button ref click may be simpler).

Keep in mind that if you want to "restore" the field values after submitting, you need to return them from the loader function like this:

```
// Loader function
 const url = new URL(request.url);

 return {
  results: [...], 
  values: Object.fromEntries(url.searchParams.entries())
 };
```

Then in the component, use `values` from `useLoaderData`:

```
<input type="text" name="max" defaultValue={values.max || ""}/>
```

Added benefit: if you come back to this page (by clicking browser back for example), your search parameters and search results are still there!

I actually put up a stackblitz for you but I lost all my changes :(

Comment: Thanks for the help, Komo! I actually need a portion of the form (section with the checkboxes) to be submitted automatically.  I found a bit of a workaround to keep things under hidden fields. but it seems like an awful workaround. just feels like there's a better way to do it. 

No worries about the stackbitz. haha

Comment: by the way, I updated the question with the UI of what i'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could just keep all fields in a single form and submit that form when the submit button is pressed.

Then onChange, check if the target's name is 'status', and submit the form anyway.

```
export default function App() {
  const submit = (form) => {
    form.submit();
  };

  return (
    <form
      name="search"
      action="/search"
      method="get"
      onChange={(e) => {
        if (e.target.name === "status") {
          submit(e.currentTarget);
        }
      }}
    >
      <fieldset>
        <legend>status</legend>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="status" value="buy_now" />
          buy_now
        </label>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="status" value="on_auction" />
          on_auction
        </label>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset>
        <legend>price</legend>

        <label>
          <div>blockchain</div>
          <select name="blockchain">
            <option value="option_1">Blockchain Option 1</option>
            <option value="option_2">Blockchain Option 2</option>
          </select>
        </label>
        <label>
          min <input type="number" name="min" />
        </label>
        <label>
          max <input type="number" name="max" />
        </label>
      </fieldset>
      <button type="submit">Apply</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-ully-dfn5u?file=/src/App.js:247-252)

Note: not sure what your motivation is to want to separate this into separate forms, but I think the *magic* you're referring to is that server state, URLSearchParams, FormData and UI are all aligned because they are using the same underlying data using only common web APIs.